# Default keyboard is changed when I close my app

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am working with keyboard project.
Everything is working fine but when I closed my application which is used for keyboard theme selection, my keyboard is removed from default keyboard...

After this I want to re-select my keyboard then it works fine.

My question is: Why does the default keyboard change when I close the app? Anyone knows why this happens?

Note : This problem only happens on custom OSs like Vivo or Funtouch OS. It's working fine in Samsung and other mobile devices, etc.

Comment: Are you testing on Mi device ?

Comment: No testing done with Android Emulator And Vivo V7 Plus

Comment: You can't set the global default keyboard programatically.  Only the user can, and only through settings.

Comment: I knows That Brother I set The Keyboard from Setting Problem Come When App Close Its Removed, Then I want To reselect Keyboard from setting

Comment: Can you show some of your code?

Comment: which code ?  Keybord service

Comment: @GhostCat i need help to solve this problem if know then post releted answer thank you

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert here. I dont understand why Android comes back and wants me to select my preferred keyboard APP from time to time either ;-(